# How do I fix an unexpected nil object error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I have this error when I try to add a comment via AJAX:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_key):
1: $("#<%= dom_id(@comment.comment_title) %>").parent().append('<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>');
2: $(".comment_form")[0].reset();
  app/views/comments/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments_create_js_erb___503385093_2173588800_0'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

The form to create the comment has an association option that should set the `comment_title` for the `comment`:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new], :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles.map {|ct| [ct.title, comment_title_path(ct)] }, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :placeholder => "Post a comment." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :value => "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the create action in my comments controller:

```
def create
  @comment = @video.comments.new(params[:comment].merge({:user_id => current_user.id}))
  if @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :alert => "Unable to add comment." }
      format.js { render 'fail_create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I resolve this?

Comment: why did you delete previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use this:

```
dom_id(@comment.comment_title)
```

You can use this

```
dom_id(@comment)
```

Because you should pass a record, but not a string

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RecordIdentifier/dom_id

**UPD**

as far as `comment_title` is a `has_one` association (but not an attribute, as I thought), so the problem is it isn't created so it passes `nil` into `dom_id` method

Comment: really? it worked before I made some changes to my application

Comment: I've never used this sugar, but API said that it wasn't

Comment: oh `comment_title` isn't a string, it's an object

Comment: a comment_title has many comments, and a comment belongs to a comment_title... look at my form

Comment: ok. So `coment_title` is nil for this particular `@comment`. You didn't speecify it in your controller. You've created `@comment` but not `comment_title` for it.

Comment: ok `@comment.comment_title` is definitely nil, so it's a problem with the form

Comment: it should, but as you can see - it isn't created. Debug your params and debug why `comment_title` isn't created. You start point is: comment_title is not created.

Comment: no `comment_title` is created, but `@comment.comment_title` is not, if you look at my `f.association` line in my form, it worked before I added the `.map{}` code, but i need that code...

Comment: I've never used `simple_form_for` so I don't know what is going on there and what is your issue there. And it is another issue, actually

Comment: what do you mean it is another issue? isn't it that the association is not being created?

Comment: Yes, it is. So now you need to figure out how `assosiation` method works in your `simple_form`. Best way to do it - to read documentation